# mongoErrorContextSymbolError :with node?

Tags: mongodb

I tried to connect to Mongo DB that's not working.

Could you confirm my error?

[image]

server.js

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');

    const typeDefs = require('./typeDefs');

    const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

    const mongoose = require('mongoose')

    require('dotenv').config();


    mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true ,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      })
      .then(() => console.log('DB conncted'))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

    const server = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers
    })

    server.listen().then(({url}) => {
      console.log(`Server listening on ${url}`);
    });
```

.env

```
**MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://Taiga:taiga@taiga-6d1ty.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority**
```

Another

I tried to this that's not working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKWAvwtfsoc

The reason that

mongodb+srv://taiga-6d1ty.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority/RestApi_youtube

I don't know what is "RestApi_youtube"

Where has this name?